# How can I write the length function in one line?

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function

*EDIT Why vote down a university tutorial Q?*

Tutorial problem is to write a single line function for length of a list <strike>an array</strike>.

Example given of a one line function is this type of expression. **The specific function in this example is not relevant**, just the fact that it uses an anonymous function (I think), uses the `where` syntax and is all on a single line

```
f = f' where f' 1 = 0; f' x = x + f' (x-1)
```

I cannot solve but would like to know some ways.

[image: coursework context for this question on SO]

Comment: What does this have to do with an array? Aren't `if` expressions (instead of pattern matching) enough for exactly what you want to do? Isn't this just `-1 + n * (n + 1) / 2`?

Comment: Hint: take  a look at `foldr`/`foldl`.

Comment: @Chase I think the example code is just an arbitrary function written on one line, which otherwise has nothing to do with the requirements. And I assume by Array the OP means List - although very different things in Haskell (as they are when talking specifically about data structures) the terms are often interchangeable in imperative languages. (Which tend to have arrays not lists built in, but sometimes refer to an array as a "list".)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Ahh, that would make sense.

Comment: `myLen xs = if null xs then 0 else 1 + [recursive call here - might want some function to make the list shorter ...]`

Comment: for those voting down the question, it was a problem set in week to a of Haskell course running at Glasgow University — might mean something to some of you who know Haskell — which I've only just started on. the idea was to do it without relying any fancy library functions, it's week 2, some of us didn't know anything at this point in the course.

Comment: I understand nobody would ever want to use this in production code, but I wanted to know what they were asking for at the time. :-)

Comment: @Chase the example was unrelated to the length' function being asked for. just an example of a one line function using very primitive constructs. I'll edit Q to be clearer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this was Wk 2 in my Haskell course, we hadn't seen folds yet, it's a pretty `off-topic` Q I must admit!

Comment: "it uses an anonymous function" no, it's not anonymous, it has a name, `f'` -- but, this name is internal, and this function is internal, and this name is only known inside `f` so it is just like using an unnamed function, but  more convenient. :)

Comment: the problem that could cause the dvs is the lack of timely engagement on your part. :) IOW had you stayed in touch and explained the background to the question the reaction would probably be different. I wouldn't have written the answer that way, too. so looking at the page you've now included, it already gives all the solutions to you, and it was just a typing exercise -- and it _is_ important to type your own code in, since we learn better that way. so just go ahead and type the `if` or the `... | ...` code all on one line, & see for yourself that it works just as the page is telling you. :)

Comment: @WillNess yes looking back at the whole page, which I wasn't when I put this question, I could have rewrote their if-then-else on one line, but I was trying to use an anonymous function also using where and semicolons. Agree I should have engaged the responses more immediately. TBH I think I moved on to another

Comment: [cont] @WillNess TBH I think I moved on to any other of the problems I had with uncompiled code etc as a newb. I'm finding Learn Your Some Haskell great remedial instruction and just discovered a 2 semester lecture series on YT by Graham Hutton  — who is brilliantly articulate and gentle on the student at the same time.

Comment: @Will, thx yes I knew it wasn't really an anonymous function but didn't know the word internal describes it. Thx again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*update:*  Now that you've provided the background to the question, looking at the page you've now included, it already gives you all the solutions -- it was just a typing exercise. It *is* important to type your own code in, since we learn better that way. Thus the solutions are:

```
leng1 lst = if lst==[] then 0 else let { x:xs = lst } in ...

leng2 lst | lst==[] = ... | otherwise = ...

leng3 lst = f lst where f [] = 0 ; f ... = ...
```

Moreover, what the page is saying about the two-clauses definition is not right. It can too be entered on one line, also with the `;` separating the clauses:

```
leng0 [] = 0 ; leng0 (x:xs) = 1 + leng0 xs
```

They all do work when you enter them on one line, just as the page was telling you.

(yes you might need those extra `{}` and `()` for it to work, compared with the code on the page).

<sub>(the original version of the answer follows:)</sub>

---

One line implementation of `length` of an array:

```
lenArr = succ . negate . uncurry (-) . bounds
```

One line implementations of `length` of a list:

```
lenLs = \ xs -> sum [1 | _x <- xs]
      = getSum . foldMap (\ _x -> Sum 1)
      = flip (foldr (\ _x r i -> r $! (i+1)) id) 0
      = flip (foldr ((.) . const (+1)) id) 0
      = flip (foldr ((.) . const (+1)) (const 0)) ()
      = foldr ((+) . const (1)) 0
      = foldr (($) . const (+1)) 0
      = foldr ($) 0 . (succ <$)
      = \ xs -> let {ys = 0 : zipWith (\ a b -> a+1) ys xs} in last ys
      = last . scanl (\ a b -> a+1) 0
      = foldl (\ a b -> a+1) 0
      = foldl' (\ a b -> a+1) 0
      = ...
```

Comment: BTW I was thinking of http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html when writing this. perhaps haven't succeeded much with that. :)